# How to combine multiple OR in SQL query

Tags: oracle, join

I have 2 tables that I JOIN.

From T1 I only need customers that match 1 value.

From T2 I need to list all customers that answered 'Y' to at least one of the 12 questions. I am trying to avoid repeating 'OR' 12 times. There has to be a better way. This is what I have so far.

```
SELECT T1.ID, T1.Name, T1.Value, T2.Q1, T2.Q2, ... T2.Q12
FROM T1
  RIGHT JOIN T2 on T1.ID=T2.ID
WHERE T2.Q1='Y'
OR T2.Q2='Y'
OR T2.Q3='Y'
...
...
OR T2.Q12='Y'
AND T1.Value='9'
```

Comment: Two remarks: `AND` is evaluated before `OR` (add parenthesis) and the `AND T1.Value='9'` results in an inner join instead of outer. Instead of `OR` use `IN`: `'Y' IN (Q1,Q2,Q3,...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, `IN` is used the other way around, single column compared to multiple constants, but you can also compare a single constant to multiple columns:

`WHERE 'Y' IN (T2.Q1, T2.Q2, ..., T2.Q12)`

Note that, in the background, Oracle will rewrite this as (your original query):

`T2.Q1 = 'Y' or T2.Q2 = 'Y' ... or T2.Q12 = 'Y'`

Comment: The very fact that you are having to do that OR against such a series of columns strongly suggests a flawed table design.  While we don't know that actual nature and meaning of each column, it sure looks as if you were to normalize the design to Third Normal Form, those columns would be one column each in individual rows of a child table.  And if so your query would become trivial.